# Trigonometric identity involving half angles

Tags: trigonometry

Ok.here is the problem in the picture below.

[image]
How do I get these results?

Given that d equals

[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Answer (score 1):

That is the definition. $$\frac{1}{\tan(x)} = \cot(x)$$